# Save searches in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to save a search information in Visual Studio. For example if I'm constantly searching for "This string", match case, match whole word, look in 'Current Project'.  Can I store this somehow as a saved search?

Comment: VS does save the search/replace strings itself, but I doubt the other options can be saved. Maybe you can record a macro that does that that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do with a macro.  Start with Tools + Macros + Record.  Do a search, setting all the options you want, click Stop Recording.  View + Other Windows + Macro Explorer.  Rename the "TemporaryMacro" to something more suitable.  Tools + Customize + Keyboard and assign a keystroke to the macro.

You now have a single keystroke to execute the search.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you do the following in VS2012:

1) Copy and paste the file types list back into the "Look at these file types" search box

2) Click and unclick the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox

3) Press "Find Next" before "Find All"

4) Close visual studio and reopen the solution

For the actual search string I think if you make sure your cursor is positioned on a blank line, it will also reuse the last search string, otherwise it will pick the string under the cursor.

Then (at least VS2012) will remember the last search options. You may or may not also need to click your heels and perform some voodoo magic that i was doing at the time on the side (that part is a secret, sorry)